# Hide keyboard Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, keyboard, windows-phone-8.1

When I try to add a text in the TextBox from a canvas using handwriting, the cursor go to the TextBox and the keyboard shows, and I try to add some code like make the TextBox isReadonly or trying to hide the keyboard and doesn't work.
I want every time select an item from the ListBox the item add to the TextBox without showing the keyboard. the action on RecognizedListBox_SelectionChanged a ListBox

```
private void RecognizedListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RecognizedListBox.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

            //gte the selected item from listbox
            string inputTextWritePad = RecognizedListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //add the item to RichEditBox
            MyTextNote.Text += inputTextWritePad + " ";
            //clear the canvas  return the listbox to vide
            ClearAllClick(sender, e);  
    }
```

If I add isReadonly for TextBox, it will permanent disable to edit it, and I can't add any text using keyboard. I don't know where I will put my code, or verify when I need the keyboard to use it.
I see if I need to hide the keyboard, I must have an event for the keyboard button or something like this

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key==Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryHide();
    }
}
```

but nothing to figure out!!

update 1:
I add this code

```
private void MyTextNote_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryHide();
    }
```

and help me to not show the keyboard, but I need to show it when I clicked the textbox, I try whit tapped but nothing help.

Comment: If you are okay with disabling your TextBox, why not use a Label instead?

Comment: I don't want to disable my textbox, I use a handwriting recognition to add some word, if there are some mistaken word, I want try to modify it, so I need the textbox

Comment: try setting focus off your TextBox.

Comment: This doesn't work in WP 8.1 app. only Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryHide();

Comment: I found this interesting property [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.preventkeyboarddisplayonprogrammaticfocus.Aspx) which should help you : 
`<TextBox PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="bool"/>`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a property to avoid displaying Keyboard if your TextBox receives focus programmatically :

```
<TextBox PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="true"/>
```

> Set this property to true to prevent the onscreen touch keyboard from
>   showing when focus is programmatically set on a text box. By default,
>   the onscreen touch keyboard is displayed whenever focus moves to an
>   editable text box and the most recent input was generated by touch.

[Official Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.preventkeyboarddisplayonprogrammaticfocus.Aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I need the keyboard off all the time, only when I need to edit the textbox, the keyboard  shows, see my new update 1

Comment: I currently don't have access to WP8.1 SDK so I can't try it on my own, but looking at your code, I have following remarks :
In your first handler, `TextBox_KeyUp`, the keyboard will hide when you tap <Enter> key, which should work but, in your case, is of no use.
And in `MyTextNote_GotFocus`, even if this work, you wont be able to edit the text as it will always hide the keyboard.
The two solutions I can imagine is setting the focus to something else, your page for example (Adding `this.focus();` in ListSelectionChanged after setting text or try determining how the TextBox receives its focus.